# How to access the XML declaration with minidom (python)

Tags: python, xml, minidom

In python, with minidom, is it possible to read/modify the XML declaration?

I have a xml file which starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
```

and I'd like for e.g. to change it to

```
<?xml-stylesheet href='form.xslt' type='text/xsl' ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both `<?xml ?>` and `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` (they known as *processing instructions*, btw) in one XML. To add one, simply create an instance of [`ProcessingInstruction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#processinginstruction-objects) object and append it before the root element, for example :

```
from xml.dom import minidom

source = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root/>"""
doc = minidom.parseString(source)
pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="form.xslt"')
doc.insertBefore(pi, doc.firstChild)
print(doc.toprettyxml())
```

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xslt"?>
<root/>
```